# root test applied to power series

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

When I apply the root test to power series I know that

$$R= \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}}$$

So if I get $1$ as the result of the limit the radius of convergence of the power series is $R=1$?

Same question also for the ratio test.

I'm confused because when I study the behaviour of numerical series with these criteria and I get 1 as a result it means that they are not applicable.

The prove of the ratio test given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) though seems to me clear in indicating that in the power series case $1$ is not a problematic result.

Comment: Yes and yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Yeeeeees don't confused the Radius of convergence and the criteria for simple series

Comment: Thank you I'll keep in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply the ratio test to $\sum c_n z^n$:
$$
(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\root n\of{|c_n|})|z| =
\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\root n\of{|c_n z^n|} < 1
$$
implies that the series is convergent for 
$$|z| < \frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}}}.$$